# Java Swing GUI JTable setting rows to invisible

Tags: java, swing

In a Java Swing GUI How can I hide (make invisible) a selected row in JTable?
Basically the user presses a button gets the selected row and makes the row invisible. As you can see this code creates a GUI with a table once the row is selected print that row corresponding number to the command by way of a button event my trouble is setting the row to invisible

```
public class EmployeeSearchApp extends JFrame {
    private static  Connection connect;
    private JLabel title = new JLabel();

    private JPanel contentPane;
    private JTextField lastNameTextField;
    private JButton btnSearch;
    private JScrollPane scrollPane;
    private JTable table;
    private JButton appartmentformbutton = new JButton();
    private JButton selectbutton = new JButton();
    private JButton logoutexitbutton = new JButton();
    private JComboBox  addresscb = new JComboBox();
    private JComboBox  sexcb = new JComboBox();
    private JComboBox  agecb = new JComboBox();
    private JComboBox coursecb = new JComboBox();
    private JComboBox jobcb = new JComboBox();  
    static String loginusername;
    static String loginpassword;
    private EmployeeDAO employeeDAO;
    static EmployeeSearchApp searchouse = new EmployeeSearchApp(loginusername, loginpassword);
    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    searchouse.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create the frame.
     */
    public EmployeeSearchApp(String loginusername, String loginpassword) {
         this.loginusername=loginusername;
            this.loginpassword=loginpassword;
            if(loginusername!=null && loginpassword!=null){
            System.out.print(loginusername +loginpassword);
            }
        // create the DAO
        try {
            employeeDAO = new EmployeeDAO();
        } catch (Exception exc) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Error: " + exc, "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE); 
        }
        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setTitle("Search for house");
        setAutoRequestFocus(false);
        setBackground(new java.awt.Color(204, 204, 255));
        setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
        contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(204, 204, 255));
        contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        contentPane.setLayout(new BorderLayout(0, 0));
        setContentPane(contentPane);
        title.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 1, 24)); // NOI18N
        title.setText("               Looking for Appartment");
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(204, 204, 255));
        FlowLayout flowLayout = (FlowLayout) panel.getLayout();
        flowLayout.setAlignment(FlowLayout.LEFT);
        contentPane.add(panel, BorderLayout.NORTH);

        JLabel lblEnterLastName = new JLabel("Enter last name");
        panel.add(title);
        panel.add(lblEnterLastName);




        lastNameTextField = new JTextField();
        panel.add(lastNameTextField);
        lastNameTextField.setColumns(10);



        logoutexitbutton.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() 
        {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) 
            {

                Component frame = null;
                int n = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(
                        frame,
                        "Exit to Main Screen",
                        "Exit to Main Screen",
                        JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
                        searchouse.dispose();
                        intro  cancellogin = new intro();
                        cancellogin.setVisible(true);
            }
        });

        addresscb.setModel(new javax.swing.DefaultComboBoxModel<>(new String[] { "Location", 
                "Willow View", "Carton Drive", "Ballykeeran", "Moydrum",
                "Valley Court", "Auburn Heights", "Cypress Gardens", "Old Willow Park", "Old Willow Place",
                "Willow Park", "Wellmount Apartments", "Erris Grove, Willow Park", "Willow Green",
                "Cartontroy", "Crystal Village", "Willow Grove", "Willow Cresent",
                "Thornbury Drive", "Willow Place, Willow Park", "Willow View", "Willow Drive",
                "Small Apartments", "Other"}));

        sexcb.setModel(new javax.swing.DefaultComboBoxModel<>(new String[] { "Sex", "Male", "Female"}));
        agecb.setModel(new javax.swing.DefaultComboBoxModel<>(new String[] { "Age", "18", "19", "20", "21", "22", "23", "24", "25", "26", "27", "28", "29", "30", "31", "32", "33", "34", "35", "36", "37", "38", "39", "40"}));
        coursecb.setModel(new javax.swing.DefaultComboBoxModel<>(new String[] { "Course", "Software Design", "Cooking", "Science" }));
        jobcb.setModel(new javax.swing.DefaultComboBoxModel<>(new String[] { "Job", "Guard", "Teacher", "Farmer" }));


        appartmentformbutton.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 1, 11)); // NOI18N
        appartmentformbutton.setText("<html>Appartment<br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Form</html>");

        logoutexitbutton.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 1, 11)); // NOI18N
        logoutexitbutton.setText("Log Out");

        selectbutton.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 1, 11)); 
        selectbutton.setText("Select Row");


        btnSearch = new JButton("Search");
        btnSearch.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                // Get last name from the text field

                // Call DAO and get employees for the last name

                // If last name is empty, then get all employees

                // Print out employees              

                try {
                    String lastName = lastNameTextField.getText();

                    List<Employee> employees = null;

                    if (lastName != null && lastName.trim().length() > 0) {
                        employees = employeeDAO.searchEmployees(lastName);
                    } else {
                        employees = employeeDAO.getAllEmployees();
                    }

                    // create the model and update the "table"
                    EmployeeTableModel model = new EmployeeTableModel(employees);

                    table.setModel(model);

                    /*
                    for (Employee temp : employees) {
                        System.out.println(temp);
                    }
                    */
                } catch (Exception exc) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(EmployeeSearchApp.this, "Error: " + exc, "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE); 
                }

            }
        });




        selectbutton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            int selectedRow = table.getSelectedRow();
            //TableRowModel tcm = table.getColumnModel();
            if(selectedRow != -1) {
                //table.removeColumn(table.getColumnModel().getSelectedColumn());
                table.getSelectedRow();
                //got selected row
                //database select Apartment get name and id
                System.out.print(selectedRow);
                //System.out.print(loginusername + ","+loginpassword);

                //send to table
                //set visibity to false
                //prints out db taken
                //fix gui set up
                //finish out combo boxes
                //










            }}});











        panel.add(btnSearch);
        panel.add(appartmentformbutton);
        panel.add(selectbutton);
        panel.add(logoutexitbutton);
        panel.add(addresscb);
        panel.add(sexcb);
        panel.add(agecb );
        panel.add(coursecb);
        panel.add(jobcb);


        scrollPane = new JScrollPane();
        contentPane.add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        table = new JTable();
        scrollPane.setViewportView(table);
    }

}
```

Comment: As per the numerous duplicates of this question -- you use row filtering.

Comment: [Links to other similar questions](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=site:stackoverflow.com+java+hide+jtable+row&*)

Comment: Ok thanks. How should I do it instead so @camickr

Comment: So the real question is what happens after the row is hidden? Can you ever make the row visible again? If not, then you could just delete the row from the table. If the hidden rows can be restored then the solution is more complex. We don't have enough information to provide a proper solution.

Comment: So my application is an online rent finder so a user can select an apartment in a row then whoever clicked this row has there details sent to a database and a confirmation message is sent back. However if next year that apartment is available all the administrator will have to do is change the visibility of that row rather than deleting it from the database. Will removing the row only remove it from the GUI & not the database as the data is for the table is got using JDBC if it only removes it from the GUI and not the database I see no reason I can't remove it but how do you remove it @camickr

Comment: `Will removing the row only remove it from the GUI & not the database` - A JTable is used to display data. It has no knowledge where the data comes from. So you can change the table any way you please without affecting the original data source, unless of course you have logic in your application to automatically update the source when the table is changed.

Comment: @William `I see no reason I can't remove it` - then you need to add a `removeRow(...)` type of method to your EmployeeTableModel. For an example of how this might be implement check out: [Row Table Model](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/11/21/row-table-model/).